# Flask app: Error while trying to deploy kubernetes resources "No data received!"

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, flask, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to create an app that could allow users to deploy Kubernetes resources via a drag and drop interface, and since I have only some novice knowledge about the subject I am stuck in a part where when I drag and drop the Kube element I face this error on the browser [image]

And on the prompt the following messages:

```bash
sudo docker run -p 8080:5000 hyperkube:v8
time="2023-04-17T11:01:22.096360723+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
time="2023-04-17T11:01:22.096662484+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
time="2023-04-17T11:01:22.096674271+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
time="2023-04-17T11:01:22.097304112+02:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/9b8dcf1a36e0cb504c211db088c3c5d5c2d93be56e5a2d2d68ec68e6a213df3b pid=1774 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 490-951-784
172.17.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2023 09:01:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2023 09:01:41] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.17.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2023 09:01:43] "POST /deploy HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

here's the Dockerfile I am using

```bash
# Use the official Python base image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the app.py and index.html files to the container
COPY app.py /app
COPY templates /app/templates

# Install Flask and Kubernetes Python client
RUN pip install Flask kubernetes

# Expose the port that the app will run on
EXPOSE 5000

# Start the Flask app
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

and here's the Dlask app code :

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/deploy', methods=['POST'])
def deploy():
    try:
        if request.form:
            # Get the form data from the request
            container_image = request.form.get('image')
            name = request.form.get('name')
            replicas = request.form.get('replicas')
            deployment_type = request.form.get('type')

            if not container_image or not name or not replicas or not deployment_type:
                return 'Incomplete data provided!', 400

            # Load the Kubernetes configuration
            config.load_kube_config()

            # Create a Kubernetes API client
            api_client = client.ApiClient()

            # Deploy pod, deployment, or statefulset based on the type
            if deployment_type == 'pod':
                # Define the pod spec
                pod_spec = client.V1PodSpec(containers=[client.V1Container(name=name, image=container_image)])
                # Create the pod object
                pod = client.V1Pod(metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name=name), spec=pod_spec)
                # Create the pod using the API client
                api_client.create_namespaced_pod(body=pod, namespace='default')
                return 'Pod deployed successfully!'
            elif deployment_type == 'deployment':
                # Define the deployment spec
                deployment_spec = client.V1DeploymentSpec(replicas=replicas,
                                                           selector=client.V1LabelSelector(match_labels={"app": name}),
                                                           template=client.V1PodTemplateSpec(
                                                               metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(labels={"app": name}),
                                                               spec=client.V1PodSpec(
                                                                   containers=[client.V1Container(
                                                                       name=name, image=container_image)])))
                # Create the deployment object
                deployment = client.V1Deployment(metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name=name), spec=deployment_spec)
                # Create the deployment using the API client
                api_client.create_namespaced_deployment(body=deployment, namespace='default')
                return 'Deployment deployed successfully!'
            elif deployment_type == 'statefulset':
                # Define the statefulset spec
                statefulset_spec = client.V1StatefulSetSpec(replicas=replicas,
                                                             selector=client.V1LabelSelector(match_labels={"app": name}),
                                                             template=client.V1PodTemplateSpec(
                                                                 metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(labels={"app": name}),
                                                                 spec=client.V1PodSpec(
                                                                     containers=[client.V1Container(
                                                                         name=name, image=container_image)])))
                # Create the statefulset object
                statefulset = client.V1StatefulSet(metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name=name), spec=statefulset_spec)
                # Create the statefulset using the API client
                api_client.create_namespaced_stateful_set(body=statefulset, namespace='default')
                return 'StatefulSet deployed successfully!'
            else:
                return 'Invalid deployment type!', 400
        else:
            return 'No data received!', 400
    except ApiException as e:
        return 'Error creating Kubernetes resource: {}'.format(e), 500
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Error processing request: {}'.format(e), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

and here's the index.html template I am using :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Deploy Pod/Deployment/StatefulSet</title>
    <!-- Add CSS dependencies -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        /* custom CSS styles */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Drag-and-Drop UI Components</h1>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <!-- Add your drag-and-drop UI components here -->
                <div class="card" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Pod</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Drag me to deploy a pod</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Deployment</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Drag me to deploy a deployment</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">StatefulSet</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Drag me to deploy a statefulset</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <!-- Add your drop area(s) here -->
                <div class="card" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Drop Area</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Drop here to deploy</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add JS dependencies -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Add your JavaScript logic for drag-and-drop here
        function drag(event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.outerHTML);
        }

        function allowDrop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function drop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            // Send the drag-and-drop data to the Flask app for deployment
            fetch('/deploy', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({data: data})
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => {
                alert(result);  // Show deployment result
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I will be grateful for any leads or corrections to understand what prevention the app from deploying the resource as expected.

P.S: I am using WSL2 as a work environment

````bash
uname -a
Linux CPX-NIIK2XBP8BL 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux```
````